# How to read a list of Path names as a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

How do I read a list of paths as a pyspark dataframe (azure databricks)?

Sample :-

```
file_paths=[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path1.csv', name='path1.csv',size=520283136),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path2.csv',name='path2.csv', size=565211023),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path3.csv'name='path3.csv', size=545199423),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path4.csv',name='path4.csv' size=511559759),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path5.csv', name='path5.csv', size=532738818),
 FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path6.csv', name='path6.csv', size=521915460)]
```

Comment: Can you please clarify about what you mean by reading list of files as pyspark dataframe? Do you want to read all those files into a single dataframe?

Comment: Yes.They all have same column names

Comment: Hey @Scope, in the sample that you provided, for FileInfo, the `path` attribute indicates the file name as `path1.csv` but the `name` attribute indicates that the name is `e.csv`. Can you please clarify about this?

Comment: its just a sample. how do i read list of fileinfo paths that is my question, anyway ive corrected that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate on this list you can simply do a `for` loop
:

```py
dfs = {}
for file_info in file_paths:
  print(f'loading {file_info.name} from {file_info.path=}')
  dfs[file_info.name.replace('.csv','')] = spark.read.option('header',True).csv(file_info.path)
  
dfs['path_1'].select('seq','name','zip','date').show()

> loading path_1.csv from file_info.path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path_1.csv'
> loading path_2.csv from file_info.path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path_2.csv'
> loading path_3.csv from file_info.path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path_3.csv'
> loading path_4.csv from file_info.path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path_4.csv'
> loading path_5.csv from file_info.path='dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/path_5.csv'
+---+----------+-----+----------+
|seq|      name|  zip|      date|
+---+----------+-----+----------+
|  1|   Rebecca|13336|11/15/2055|
|  2|    Maggie|18310|04/21/1932|
|  3|    Ronnie|93307|06/03/1950|
|  4|     Lydia|88951|01/22/1945|
|  5|      Lida|30880|08/13/2002|
+---+----------+-----+----------+
```

If all CSVs files have the same schema, but you want to apply different rules, you could load them all in a single dataframe with a "filename" column as follows :

```py
from  pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name ,split, element_at
df = spark.read.option('header',True).csv("dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/*/*.csv").withColumn("filename",element_at(split(input_file_name(),'/'),-1))
df.show()
 

---+----------+-----+----------+------------+
|seq|     name|  zip|      date|    filename|
+---+---------+-----+----------+------------+
|  1|  Rebecca|13336|11/15/2055|  path_1.csv|
|  2|   Maggie|18310|04/21/1932|  path_2.csv|
|  3|   Ronnie|93307|06/03/1950|  path_3.csv|
|  4|    Lydia|88951|01/22/1945|  path_4.csv|
|  5|     Lida|30880|08/13/2002|  path_5.csv|
+---+---------+-----+----------+------------+
```

You can then use the `.where` clause to apply transformations on rows by filename.

There is also the option `recursiveFileLookup` that I have found slightly more performant when dealing with lots of subdirectories.

```py
df = (spark.read`
        .option("recursiveFileLookup",True)
        .csv("dbfs:/mnt/OUTPUT/")         
       )
```

Comment: No I meant how do I iterate on the list of paths

Comment: Why do you want to iterate ? Are you going to apply different transformations ?

Comment: I have updated my answer with two methods to iterate on the list of paths.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the `print` statement? w/o accessing path like `dfs['path_1'].select('seq','name','zip','date').show()` I want data from all the paths as one single `df`

Comment: The print statement requires python 3.9+. If you don't, then just remove the ```=``` sign and it should work

Comment: If you want all the paths in a single ```df``` then the second and third option are the one you are looking for.